# Develop Lambda function Locally only using sam cli

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, nestjs, aws-sam-cli

So, I want to create a basic lambda function with one or two routes locally and then deploy it to aws from local. This has to be done in nestjs itself.

I was able to do the same with serverless package in nestjs.

Now, my task is to do the same thing without using serverless but to do it with sam cli and aws cli and docker.

After searching for some time i found out sam cli has sam init operation with some guided packages and examples. Basically speaking it lets you choose the language and a starter example. Since im using nestjs for this task sam cli doesnot have it. Been searching for so long and tried other approaches but none of them worked.

Is there any proper way to do it with sam cli and nestjs?
Can someone guide me or provide me with something?